# Rails 4: ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, nested-resources, nested-routes

I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

And here are my routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :administrations
  resources :calendars
end
```

———————————

**UPDATE:**

Here is what I get when I run `rake routes` in Terminal:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                        Controller#Action
    user_administrations GET    /users/:user_id/administrations(.:format)          administrations#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/administrations(.:format)          administrations#create
 new_user_administration GET    /users/:user_id/administrations/new(.:format)      administrations#new
edit_user_administration GET    /users/:user_id/administrations/:id/edit(.:format) administrations#edit
     user_administration GET    /users/:user_id/administrations/:id(.:format)      administrations#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/administrations/:id(.:format)      administrations#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/administrations/:id(.:format)      administrations#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/administrations/:id(.:format)      administrations#destroy
          user_calendars GET    /users/:user_id/calendars(.:format)                calendars#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/calendars(.:format)                calendars#create
       new_user_calendar GET    /users/:user_id/calendars/new(.:format)            calendars#new
      edit_user_calendar GET    /users/:user_id/calendars/:id/edit(.:format)       calendars#edit
           user_calendar GET    /users/:user_id/calendars/:id(.:format)            calendars#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/calendars/:id(.:format)            calendars#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/calendars/:id(.:format)            calendars#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/calendars/:id(.:format)            calendars#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                                   users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                                   users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                               users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                          users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                               users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                               users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                               users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                               users#destroy
                    root GET    /                                                  static_pages#home
```

———————————

**UPDATE 2**:

Here is my `calendars_controller.rb` file:

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_calendar, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /calendars
  # GET /calendars.json
  def index
    @calendars = Calendar.all
  end

  # GET /calendars/1
  # GET /calendars/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /calendars/new
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @calendar = @user.calendars.new
  end

  # GET /calendars/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @calendar = @user.calendar.find(params[:calendar_id])
  end

  # POST /calendars
  # POST /calendars.json
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @calendar = @user.calendars.new(calendar_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @calendar.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_calendar_path(@user,@calendar), notice: 'Calendar was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @calendar }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @calendar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /calendars/1
  # PATCH/PUT /calendars/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @calendar.update(calendar_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @calendar, notice: 'Calendar was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @calendar }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @calendar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /calendars/1
  # DELETE /calendars/1.json
  def destroy
    @calendar.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calendars_url, notice: 'Calendar was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_calendar
      @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def calendar_params
      params.require(:calendar).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

———————————

`http://localhost:3000/users/1/calendars/new` and `http://localhost:3000/users/1/calendars/1` work fine.

But, whenever I try to access `http://localhost:3000/users/1/calendars`, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Calendars#index
Showing /Users/TXC/code/rails/calendy/app/views/calendars/index.html.erb where line #17 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"calendars", :id=>nil, :user_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id, :user_id]
Extracted source (around line #17):

      <tr>
        <td><%= calendar.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_calendar_path(@user, @calendar) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_calendar_path(@user, @calendar) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', calendar, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
```

In particular, I don't understand the `missing required keys: [:id, :user_id]` part, since I have both `@user` and `@calendar` in my `user_calendar_path`.

Obviously, I am missing something, but I cannot figure out what.

Any idea?

Comment: post calendars_controller code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, you are hitting `http://localhost:3000/users/1/calendars` url which maps to your `calendars#index` action and the correct path for this is: `user_calendars_path` and it needs only one param `user_id` as it will take you to the index page for the user and will show all the user calendars from the database.

But, in your `index.html.erb` view, you have this:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_calendar_path(@user, @calendar) %></td>
```

which you can't have because for the `index` action in your controller, you did not set the `@user` and `@calendar`. You can use this in `show.html.erb` but not in `index.html.erb`. So, that's why you are getting this error.

**In short**, you can't have this in your `index.html.erb`:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', user_calendar_path(@user, @calendar) %></td>
```

because this is mapped to `calendars#show` action and the corresponding view should be `show.html.erb` BUT currently you have it inside `index.html.erb`!

**To answer your last question:**

> In particular, I don't understand the missing required keys: [:id,
>   :user_id] part, since I have both @user and @calendar in my
>   user_calendar_path.

Yes, you have `@user` and `@calendar` defined in your controller BUT in the `show` method AND `user_calendar_path` maps to that `calendars#show` method. But hey! you are calling this from the `index.html.erb` which corresponds to `calendars#index` action. That's what you are missing. Hope it's clear now :-)

**Finally**, the difference is subtle.

`user_calendars_path` is for `index` view which shows you all the calendars for a particular user. In this case, you have to have a `@user` set in the `index` action in your controller.

`user_calendar_path` is for `show` which will take you to a particular calendar of a particular user. In this case, you have to have `@user` and `@calendar` set in the `show` method of your controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. How should I update my `calendars_controller` to fix the problem?

Comment: If you remove: `      <tr>
        <td><%= calendar.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_calendar_path(@user, @calendar) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_calendar_path(@user, @calendar) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', calendar, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>` from the `index.html.erb` then it will work

Comment: Basically, it depends on what you want to accomplish. You can't use `user_calendar_path` inside `index.html.erb`

Comment: If you tell me you want to show in your `index` view, then I can tell you what to change. and what's possible and what's not. Please clarify your goal.

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that everything is working when I remove links to Show, Edit and Destroy actions. But how can I get links to these actions in my `index.html.erb` then?

Comment: Well, you dont! That's the work of the  `show` page and you need to have those lines in your `show.html.erb`

Comment: In other words, when a user visits `http://localhost:3000/users/:id/calendars`, I want him to be able to: 1. see a list of all his calendars, 2. go to the show page of each calendar, 3. go to the edit page each calendar and 4. destroy each calendar from the index view if necessary. Is that possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87670/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-thibaud-clement).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the `@user` and the `@calendar` in your `calendars#show` method yet. The `new` action renders your view just fine, but it doesn't know how to fill the parameters voor `@user` and `@calendar`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just added `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @calendar = @user.calendars.find(params[:calendar_id])` to `calendars#show` but the issue and the error are still showing up. Is there a problem with this code?